# Updating an ECS Service after Registering a new Task Definition gets the old task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm using Gitlab and the AWS CLI to build code to an image, register a new task with the new image and -- hopefully -- updating the service with the new task definition

In my building script, registering the new task definition with the new image is working, using the command:

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://input.json --region $AWS_REGION
```

And then I'm trying to update my service with the new task definition using

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster $AWS_ECS_CLUSTER --service $AWS_ECS_SERVICE --force-new-deployment --region $AWS_REGION
```

When I go to the task definitions in ECS, I can see the new one, but the service alwasy creates new tasks using the old task definition, even though a new one is there.

I'm guessing that there's some delay between when the `register-task-definition` command returns and when the new definition is ready.  Is there a way to check the status of the new task, or get an update so that I get new tasks with the new definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can force your ECS service to redeploy using the latest task definition revision, just adding the parameter `--task-definition` to your `ecs update-service` command.

If you specify the task definition family name, it will deploy the latest available revision:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER --service $ECS_SERVICE --task-definition $ECS_TASKDEFINITION_FAMILY_NAME --force-new-deployment --region $AWS_REGION
```

Reference [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.21/reference/ecs/update-service.html).